# Stopping a table cell highlighting on selection,

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When a table cell is selected it gets highlighted in a blue color. I'd like to prevent this happening.

I tried doing this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

But it goes blue for a second before the blue disappears. Is there a way I can avoid it appearing blue? I'd like to do something custom to the table cell instead.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has three selection styles:-

1. Blue
2. Gray
3. None

Implementation is as follows:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

     [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];       
}
```

Comment: Check this link too http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: Thanks Gill that looks like it will do the Job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the cell selection as none, blue or gray in the attributes inspector in xcode

[image]